# How to run task on specified timer from List of Structure

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a list of structure of two columns (timerMillisec & myfilename).
I need to be able to run a separate timer for each row which will open the specified filename according to the Time of its rows.

The timerMillisec is in millisecond.

Below is my List of structure and work perfect.

I'm trying to write a function that will read that list of structure and run each New Timer separately but I couldn't.

```vb
Structure StructCheckTimer

        Public timerMillisec As Long
        Public myfileName As String

        Public Sub New(ByVal verTime As Long, ByVal verFilename As String)

            Me.timerMillisec = verTime
            Me.myfileName = verFilename

        End Sub

End Structure


Public newStructCheckTimer As New List(Of StructCheckTimer)

newStructCheckTimer.Add(New StructCheckTimer("15000", "c:\myfile1.txt"))
newStructCheckTimer.Add(New StructCheckTimer("5000", "c:\myfile2.txt"))
newStructCheckTimer.Add(New StructCheckTimer("20000", "c:\myfile3.txt"))
...
```

and I read my List of structure using below

```
Dim friendsCollection As ICollection = newStructCheckTimer

        For Each s As StructCheckTimer In friendsCollection

            MsgBox(s.timerMillisec & " -- " & s.myfileName)

        Next
```

Comment: You dont need a separate timer for each item.  One time can loop thru the entire list.  Also, "15000" is not a date.  It sounds like you want a service of sorts

Comment: Date TYPE was a mistake !!!  I DO need something like `myTimer = New Timer(myMilliSecond)`  in order to put every single item which are in List of structure in to a New Timer in order to run at specified Time.

Comment: "15000" is not a Long either.  One timer can do many things at each interval, you just need to loop thru the list and check each item to see which if any need to run.  A timer is not like an alarm clock.

Comment: My concern is NOT on the List of Structure. My List of structure is working perfectly well. What I want to achieve is when I click on Button1, it should create New Timers according to the list of structure. **(the number of timers)** and set the interval time of each timer accordingly (as each row/ligne of the list has **millisec** and **filename**) value and open the specified filename when the Timer is reach zero (as usual)

Comment: But that code will not even compile under Option Strict, so it is noteworthy.  As I said Timers do not act like alarm clocks, they do not countdown or even "reach zero".  They fire an event at specified intervals for you to do something (like to check and see if it is time to do something with one of your items.).

Comment: The code and variable name has been modified in order to reflect the exact content of the variable. **I'm not trying to check the time using Timer and do something.**  As I explained above, when I click on Button1, a function needs to be able to Loop through the all List (For Each...)  and create a number of Timers in order to run each item as each row is a file which need to be open after a certain minutes.  I used Timer as it has a count down which I can easily use.

Comment: If you could advise me another way to do that I'll appreciate that too.

Comment: The code runs perfectly well under **Option Strict On" on my side !!!

Comment: Apologies for just checking. At the start of file opening, you want to wait 15s then open myFile1, then 5s later close myfile1 and open myFile2, and 20s later, close myFile2 and open myFile3, then 15s later, close myFile3 and open myFile1 and so on? Or something like the above with timings related to your structure. If it's different please let me know.